# JBOSS stuck at calling standalone.conf.bat

Tags: java, jboss, windows-7, environment-variables

Jboss wont start up no matter what, as shown in the following screencap I have set both the java_home and jboss_home environment variables, I also have jboss and java added to my path variable, it shows the calling standalone.conf.bat line and immediately stops, my OS is win7 64bit if that's of any use.

[image]

I have both java 1.8 and 1.6 installed, I switch between the two via the path variable

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out to be a very simple mistake, I set the java_16 and java_18 variables to the bin folder in the path, you should never do that, always set them up to the jdk file, since jboss already adds the \bin\java.exe part upon starting, it was reading as "JAVA="C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_45\bin\bin\java.exe"", however due to the jboss version being so old (6.1) it wouldn't show me that, I found out by downloading widlfly 8.0.0 and trying to run it, since I had found out I couldn't run any other versions of jboss, and that's when it showed me it was completing that part of the path by itself.